# Why do ¬, ∀ and ∃ have the same precedence?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, notation

I thought the order of precedence of operators and quantifiers was arbitrary, but I don't really understand why those three have the same "strength" in relation to other operators (e.g., ¬ will have precedence over ∧, but not over ∀). This leads to the rule being that ¬, ∀ and ∃ will bind to the closest predicate on their right (if I understood correctly). Why is this?

Comment: I would be very wary of ideas of precedence in first-order logic. Don't think you can write $\forall x\,A\lor B$ or $A\lor B\land C$ and have people understand what you mean.

Comment: As far as I can see, precedence of logical connectives and quantifiers can vary from author to author. I tend to write $\forall x.\ (p(x) \implies q(x))$ without parentheses, like several others. Some instead write $(\forall x.\ p(x)) \implies q$ without parentheses, using the opposite precedence. I learned to never take precedence for granted, and sometimes to use a few redundant parentheses to be sure to be understood by everyone.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Sure you can. You just have to write in the intro "All sentences are in prenex normal form unless explicitly notated otherwise with parentheses." Then you can happily write $\forall x \exists y P(x) \implies \neg Q(y)$ and no one who read the intro will be confused at all.

Comment: @Kevin: I hope that's a joke. Prenex normal forms are available only in classical logic, but more importantly, they make statements harder to understand.

Comment: @Kevin "There's a formal definition", "there are explicit conventions", and "nobody will be confused" are three very different statements.

Comment: @chi And I read "$\forall x\,p(x)\Rightarrow q(x)$" as "Oh, god, somebody who thinks there are precedence rules in first-order logic, so I'm going to have to reverse-engineer what they think those rules are."

Comment: Part of the confusion is that if you are doing Boolean algebra using standard multiplication, addition, and negation notation borrowed from ordinary algebra, then certain precedence rules are in context blindingly obvious. But if you switch notation to what has become the standard logical operators, it no longer is particularly obvious what rules of precedence apply.

Comment: You seem to come from a programming background, where you have a very strict set of rules, which are used to evaluate expressions. Logic operations are usually written for humans and they often follow loosely the definitions and conventions of other humans. When you read a few different papers on the same subject, you often need to take care, because the definitions are slightly different. So is the definition of the precedence of logic operators. Most people agree on certain conventions, but some are up to the definition of the author of the paper or be clarified by parantheses or in the text

Comment: The Oxford 'Introduction to Logic' course (for philosophers), which uses a text by Halbach, spends about two weeks (of eight) on bracketing conventions for exactly this sort of reason. Pity the undergraduates who arrived expecting to discuss Nietzsche and spend a quarter-term carefully adding and removing brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought the order of precedence of operators and quantifiers was arbitrary

Certainly the rules of precedence could be set up in different ways, but some ways are more helpful and convenient than others, and there are principled reasons for this.

> but I don't really understand why those three have the same "strength" in relation to other operators (e.g., ¬ will have precedence over ∧, but not over ∀).

Assuming you mean "strength" as a synonym for "precedence," the reason these three have the same precedence is that these operators are all **prefix** operators: as you said, their arguments are the next expressions to the right. ¬ takes the next expression as its single argument, and ∀ and ∃ each take the next two expressions. As long as you use only prefix operators, there is never ambiguity as to which operators govern which arguments: There is only one possible answer to "What's the argument of $\neg$ in $\neg \forall x \forall y P(x, y)$?" As such, precedence rules between these prefix operators would be unnecessary.

On the other hand, when you introduce **infix** operators such as ∧ (or mix in postfix operators), parsing becomes ambiguous without precedence rules or parentheses. For example, $\neg A \land B$ would be ambiguous because $\neg$ is a prefix operator and $\land$ is an infix operator. To fix this, we could just use parentheses, but in a complex expression this becomes cumbersome. Precedence rules, if agreed upon, allow us to be unambiguous with less notation. By following the rule "¬ will have precedence over ∧", we can write and read "$\neg A \land B$" and agree on what it means.

> This leads to the rule being that ¬, ∀ and ∃ will bind to the closest predicate on their right (if I understood correctly). Why is this?

I think the chain of "leading" here is backwards. Because these three are prefix operators (their arguments are the next 1 or 2 expressions to the right), there's no ambiguity between them and thus no need for precedence rules.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now!

Comment: _As long as you use only prefix operators, there is never ambiguity as to which operators govern which arguments_ And that's the beauty of Polish notation.

Answer (score 17):

Order of precedence is simply a notional convenience. There is no notion of strength here, just notation. All three operators are unary operators with notation "$\circ\  \cdot$", where $\circ$ denotes the operator symbol $\exists, \forall,\neg$ and $\cdot$ the operand. There can never be any ambiguity in which order to apply these operators: the operator to the right must always be applied to the operand first.

Hence, they have the same precedence among eachother if we consider only those three operators.  (Note that there can be ambiguity if the unary operators have different position, e.g. $-x^2$, this could mean either $(-x)^2$ or $-(x^2)$ if there was no precendence between $^2$ and $-$.)

Comment: The real question is why you would want the quantifiers to bind so tightly, assuming that most statements will be in prenex normal form and therefore need parentheses.

Comment: Certainly ¬ is unary, but I don't understand why you say that ∃ and ∀ are unary operators. For example, wouldn't you say that $∀x P(x)$ is an expression, but $∀x$ is not? Maybe you just meant to say that they're all prefix operators, and that's why there's no need for precedence rules between them.

Comment: See rule 5 at https://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs381/cs381content/logic/pred_logic/construction/wff_intro.html

Comment: @LarsH Without domain specification, the quantifiers are unary. But even when we include the specification, this is usually in a subscript, e.g. $\forall_{x \in X} P(x)$. In that case, the operator remains unambiguous in this setting.

Comment: $\forall$ and $\exists$ are not unary operators. They are *binders*, which is a feature of higher-order syntax.

Comment: @Discretelizard "Without domain specification, the quantifiers are unary." '∀ ()' is an expression without domain specification, in which ∀ takes two arguments: $x$ and $P(x)$. How is it a unary operator? (And I don't think subscripting changes the answer, even if it were a common way of writing the expression.)

Comment: Well, often the variable is implicit to the predicate. You could also argue that the most common form is $\forall_{x\in X}$, in which one argument is already provided and then unary.

Comment: "Well, often the variable is implicit to the predicate." How does that change anything? In  '$∀ $', the ∀ still has two arguments. "You could also argue that the most common form is ∀∈, in which one argument is already provided and then unary." Which argument do you mean is already provided? Are you saying that '$∀∈$', without a predicate, is a complete expression (a WFF, contrary to https://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs381/cs381content/logic/pred_logic/construction/wff_intro.html)?

Comment: No, I am saying that $\forall_{x\in X}$ can be considered as a single operator, acting on a predicate positioned to the right.